# ListenableFuture - finish after message in cluster is received and time consuming code is executed

Tags: java, akka, guava, future

At first I just want to say that I'm new to akka and Futures. So be gentle :).

I have init method in some class which returns `ListenableFuture<Boolean>`. This method should execute some time consuming code in separate thread and create akka actor which is listening to some messages in akka cluster. Future returned by init method should be completed after this actor receives certain message AND that time consuming code is finished.

How can I achieve this using ListenableFuture from Guava?

Comment: By the way: I know how to create actor and how to handle messages. I don't know how to create this future or how to chain more of them to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this. I created `ListenableFuture` containing time consuming code. At the end of this furute I created `CountDownLatch` and passed it (using creator) to akka actor. This listenable future was then blocked by `countDownLatch.await()`. Created actor with injected latch then listened to certain message in cluster. After consuming this certain message I called `countDownLatch.countDown()`. This unblocks future, where was `await()` called and future finished and returned value.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to Akka documentation about futures: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/futures.html

You can create 2 different futures, one executing the time consuming code:

```
Future<String> f1 = future(new Callable<String>() {
  public String call() {
    return "Hello" + "World";
  }
}, system.dispatcher());
```

And another one sending a message to an actor with an `ask`:

```
Timeout timeout = new Timeout(Duration.create(5, "seconds"));
Future<Object> f2 = Patterns.ask(actor, msg, timeout);
```

Finally you can use `Future.sequence` to create a single future that gets completed when both your futures are completed.

```
Iterable<Future<Integer>> listOfFutureInts = source;
Future<Iterable<Integer>> futureListOfInts = sequence(listOfFutureInts, ec);
```